# Construct Observer/Observable pattern using RxCpp

Tags: c#, c++, system.reactive, observer-pattern, rxcpp

I am trying to implement an `observer/observable` pattern in [`Rx-cpp`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp). These is a very interesting [tutorial](http://masnun.com/2012/04/13/implementing-the-observer-pattern-in-c-code-samples.html) in [`Rx.Net`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) on how someone can to this.

In this `C#` example, there are specific `interfaces` that we have to override:

```
public interface IObserver<in T>
{
    void OnCompleted();
    void OnError(Exception error);
    void OnNext(T value);
}


public interface IObservable<out T>
{
    IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer);
}
```

As far as I understand, in `Rx-cpp` there is not such a convenience. So, is it possible to provide me with some header example (`myObservable.h`/`myObserver.h`), similar to the `interfaces` above, that I can use as a guidance to define the same communication pattern?

Any help is highly appreciated,
Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks to `@zentrunix`, I am trying to make a class oriented communication. So far I have the code bellow for the observable pattern. What I want is to define a list of observers that will me attached into the observable and when an `OnNext` is called these observers should be notified. However, there are missing part.

1. How can I `subscribe()` on those observers (`Rx::subscribers<int>`) when a `myObservable::Subscribe()` functions is called.
2. Also how can I `unsubscribe()`.
3. Finally, how a corresponding `o.subscribe(onNext, onEnd);` in multiple `onNext` observers will that be? Would it be possible to construct a corresponding `myObserver` class? (again inspired by [here](http://masnun.com/2012/04/13/implementing-the-observer-pattern-in-c-code-samples.html))
4. Sorry for asking but is it meaningful such an organization? So far I was working with the architecture provided in this [tutorial](http://masnun.com/2012/04/13/implementing-the-observer-pattern-in-c-code-samples.html) and this is the reason I am obsessed with this task. I found it as a way to get involved with the `RxCpp`. Any comments are highly appreciated.<sup>(Again sorry for my ignorance.)</sup>

   ```
   class myObservable {

   private:

   std::shared_ptr<std::list<rxcpp::subscriber<int>>> observers;

   public:

   myObservable() { observers = std::make_shared<std::list<Rx::subscriber<int>>>(); };

   Rx::observable<int> Attach(std::shared_ptr<rxcpp::subscriber<int>> out) {

       return Rx::observable<>::create<int>([&, out]() {
           auto it = observers->insert(observers->end(), *out);
           it->add([=]() {
               observers->erase(it);
           });
       });

   };

   void OnNext(int sendItem) {

       for (Rx::subscriber<int> observer : *observers) {
           (observer).on_next(sendItem);
       }
   }

   void Disposer(Rx::subscriber<int> out) {

       observers->erase(std::remove(observers->begin(), observers->end(), &out), observers->end());
   };
   };
   ```

Comment: What I am trying to do is to construct two classes that inherit the `RxCpp` `observer` and `observable` functions. Ιn the `Rx.Net` example this is done by `class myIObserver : IObserver<in Τ>`. It is not how to transform a class to an `virtual` but rather how to construct the `myObserver.h` and `myObservable.h` that perform the same functionality as `SubjectObserver : IObserver<Subject>` and `SubjectObservable : IObservable<Subject>` correspondingly. Thanks for he interest.

Comment: The reason I attach the `c#` `interfaces` is because I image the same functions (`OnComplete()`,`OnNext(T value)`, etc) should be implemented whose `virtual` I didn't found.

Comment: I think your question needs to be rephrased. Also, I've just looked at some of the RxCpp source (eg. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp/blob/master/Rx/v2/src/rxcpp/rx-observer.hpp) and not seen anything that looks like an interface. I think you might be approaching this in completely the wrong way.

Comment: Your `MyObserver` should probably implement some methods like `OnNext`, and have a member `rxcpp::observer<some template arguments> m_rxObserver` which you construct by passing appropriate wrappers to those methods. Surely there are some examples of rxcpp code out there you can work from?

Comment: Good, I have tried `class myIObserver : public Rx::observer<Type T>` but there are no an `virtual` functions. Also I have tried `class myIObserver : public Rx::virtual_observer<Type T>`  but I do not know I this is ok. Also, I have serious problem in the `observable` pattern where there is no any virtual function. Thanks again.

Comment: Forget virtuals and interfaces. It looks like you should be using composition, not inheritance. That's why I said you probably needed a member. But mostly what you need is some example code.

Comment: I have searched the web about a similar example like the one I found in the `Rx.Net` but without luck. I you can suggest something it will help. Please, forgive my ignorance on the subject. Thanks again for the interest.

Comment: Is there really no documentation, no example code, no forum, no irc (or whatever) channel for rxcpp? Because if that's the case, I'd be _extremely_ hestitant to use it, because it is effectively abandonware.

Comment: General `rxcpp` examples are available, what I can not find is an example that constract a class that inherits from `rxcpp::observer`, like the one given in the `Rx.Net` example. This is the reason I am posting.

Comment: That is because **you don't inherit from `rxcpp::observer`**. Stop thinking about inheritance, interfaces, virtuals, anything like that. You don't do it. That's not how it works. That's not how the library is designed. You probably need to use composition, not inheritance. You should probably also stop looking for examples of how _not_ to use rxcpp, and instead follow some guides on how it is supposed to be used. RxCpp is not the same as rx.net, and you should not try to use them the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple example in RxCpp below.
There's (at least) one caveat though: typical RxCpp code makes heavy use of lambdas, which I dislike very much.

I've also trying to find documentation and tutorials on the internet, but couldn't find any. I'm especially interested in explanations about the threading models.

If you're willing to wade through code and Doxygen documentation, there are lots of examples in the RxCpp GitHub site.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

#include "rxcpp/rx.hpp"
namespace rx = rxcpp;

static void onNext(int n) { std::cout << "* " << n << "\n"; }
static void onEnd() { std::cout << "* end\n"; }

static void onError(std::exception_ptr ep)
{
  try { std::rethrow_exception(ep); }
  catch (std::exception& e) { std::cout << "* exception " << e.what() << '\n'; }
}

static void observableImpl(rx::subscriber<int> s)
{
  s.on_next(1);
  s.on_next(2);
  s.on_completed();
}

int main()
{
  auto o = rxcpp::observable<>::create<int>(observableImpl);
  std::cout << "*\n";
  o.subscribe(onNext, onEnd);
}
```